# Ski for hikers?

Tags: skiing, cross-country-skiing

I love hiking in the winter, especially through the snow. I would like to hike in normal shoes and be able to quickly change into some type of ski when going downhill. I know there are cross country skis, but with those its a different thing. I would like to have something small, light which I can wear on normal shoes.

So far I have found the following types of short skis, which might fit the bill:

[image]

Then there are the "bigfoot" type skis, but afaik those require real ski boots, which makes the whole thing bothersome again.

Is there a solution to my problem? Are ski skates as pictured above what I should focus on or is there something better? I would also like to be able to slide down in deep snow, outside hiking paths. Would this work?

Comment: https://colemans.com/skis-swiss-army (e.g.)

Comment: yeah like hiking shoes. Didn't ancient people just use regular shoes with their skis?

Comment: @TomasBy these seem to be about 20kg, not exactly light.

Comment: so what are these called or should I look for lighter swiss army skis? They go on regular hiking shoes right?

Comment: @TomasBy yeah, I could just bite the bullet and hike with regular skis on my back and ski boots of course. I might do that this week.

Comment: I have winter hiked in cross-country ski boots.  Even wore articulated crampons with them once, but that was 20 years ago.

Comment: why not use touring skis and use them all the time?

Comment: I haven't tries cross country skis yet, but aren't they too thin and would sink in deep snow? Are cross country skis more flexible compared to rigid ski boots, so you could hike with them?

Comment: That's the whole point of touring skis. Not a product recommendation, but something like https://www.voile.com/voile-manti-skis.html is made for that (with a min width of 10cm, there's a lot of surface to float on). With touring bindings you can lift or lock the heel, and the shoes are usually more confortable and flexible than that of alpine skis.

Comment: @TomasBy I ended up buying the skis you suggested. I have some hiking boots, that may go with these bindings. Lets see if that is enough or if I will have to get cross country ski boots or firmer hiking boots.

Comment: @TomasBy its a crampon rated hiking boot, fairly rigid, but not sure if b2 or b3 or whatever. Still not sure, if it will be enough, though. Hope to at least get down the mountain in one piece.

Comment: That sounds fine I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "short skis" that can be used with regular hiking boots. I researched those as an alternative for approaching ice climbs. However, there is some major issues with these

- They are not really suited for soft winter snow as they are simply too small and will sink in deep. They are more suited for compact (early) summer snow
- Hiking boots are very soft compared to ski boots. It will be hard to control the skis
- Bindings that go on hiking boots will not release in case of a fall

These short skis will always be a major compromise. If you focus on hiking, stick with snow shoes. If you focus on the descent, take touring skis and get a proper downhill experience.

Comment: There is no close-up view but the binding looks like it comes straight from the 60s. I am quite sure most skiers of today will have issues skiing these things properly on-piste, let alone off-piste.

Comment: But aren't touring skis too narrow, to be able to float on deep snow? Carrying touring shoes might be a compromise worth looking into, as they are a lot lighter compared to ski boots.

Comment: Touring skis is a wide range. The typical allround touring ski is something like 83-88 millimeters under the binding and these will float quite OK on deep snow. You should not forget that those skis are a lot longer than snow shoes. But there are also more powder-oriented skis which will be like 100-105 millimeters wide but a bit heavier.

Comment: I think touring skis float better than snowshoes. I don't think I've seen snow in which snowshoes would float but touring skis (or a split board) wouldn't (unless you're talking about those massive snowshoes about a meter long, but even then I'd think skis would be easier to manage)

Comment: @njzk2 a wide (freeride) ski has _times_ the surface area of a snowshoe. Also they don't scope snow up on the non-existing foot lift.